# mean evolution of 1D Fokker-Planck

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the Fokker-Planck equation on 1D with drift term $D^{(1)}(x)$, and diffusion term $D^{(2)}(x)$, and the governing equation of probability density function

$$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left( D^{(1)}(x,t) f(x,t)\right) + \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}\left( D^{(2)}(x) f(x,t)\right) $$

I'm interested in calculating $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\mathbb{E}[f]:= \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x,t)dx$.

I've come to the equation:
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x,t)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D^{(1)}(x) f(x,t)\right) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left( D^{(2)}(x) f(x,t)\right)$$

By integration by parts,
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x,t)dx = - \left[ x D^{(1)}(x) f(x,t) \right]^{\infty}_{-\infty} +  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} D^{(1)}(x) f(x,t) dx + \left[ x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D^{(2)}(x) f(x,t) \right) \right]^{\infty}_{-\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D^{(2)}(x) f(x,t) \right) dx$$

How can I simplify furthermore? And to what extent it can be simplified?

Comment: The last term should only have the first partial derivative with respect to $x$. In this term you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Moreover, one typically assumes that $f(x,t)$ decays for $x\to\pm \infty$ (because it has been normalized) such that all the boundary terms vanish...

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Fabian. I realize the equation can be simplified that way, but not all of them can go away. However, just like you said, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x,t) = 0$. What about its first and second derivatives? If so, what terms are going to zeros, and what terms are not?

Comment: One typically assumes that $f(x,t) \propto e^{-x^2/2\sigma(t)}$ and thus all boundary terms vanish... So in the end only the drift term remains.

Comment: This sounds much like Orstein-Uhlenbeck process, except for  $\sigma$ is now a function of time. Fabian, if you don't mind, would you please construct your answer rigorously? When you say boundary terms, what terms are you referring to? I seem to agree that the drift term remains, it kind of makes sense.

Comment: @Fabian: sorry, 2 years ago i was a little disrespectful. i'd like to apologize and let you know i've solved this mystery later on. thank you very much for your kind help!

Comment: that's fine. Great that you solved your question...